# Does, buying a put involve someone to sell a call?

Tags: options, call-options, put-options, counter-party

Does, buying a put involve someone to sell a call ?.

When a trade to buy put is made from one side does it means someone is selling a  call from other side. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puts and calls are both option contracts, but they are distinct and do not create or involve each other when initially written.

The writer of a **put** contract agrees to **buy** the underlying stock at the contracted strike price.

The writer sets aside a fixed amount of money (or credit) to back up the contract in case the owner of the contract exercises their option.

The writer of a **call** contract agrees to **sell** the underlying stock at the contracted strike price.

The writer either sets aside a fixed block of shares, or a variable amount of money/credit (enough to buy the promised shares immediately in the market at the variable market price) to back up the contract in case the owner of the contract exercises their option.

Most brokers require options to be traded in a margin account, so the credit to back up the contracts is established, with a process for forcing the investor to close positions if there is too much credit.

After an option is initially written, the first buyer can sell this to other buyers, or execute it (taking the writer's money or shares), or let it expire.  The writer can buy an equivalent option (that someone else has written) to close out their write, if they no longer want to promise their money or shares to their contract.

Comment: writer means a seller. Correct. As you explained above, "writer of a put contract agrees to buy" . How does it work ? Please explain. Is their a visual / animation that explains this process ?

Answer (score 8):

No, when you buy a put it means the counter-party is selling the put.

Comment: buy and sell a put. buy and sell a call. How should it make sense to a lay man ?

Comment: @nish the way he said

Comment: @nish puts and calls are different types of options contracts. Just like any other kind of transaction, trading these contracts involves one person buying and one person selling. If you're buying, someone is selling it to you

Answer (score 1):

When a security transaction occurs, there are two counter parties, a buyer and a seller.  It doesn't matter if the security is an option, a stock, a futures contract, ETF, etc.

There are more complex strategies that involves buying a put and selling a call (arbitrage) but that involves three counterparties and is a different situation.